# How to convert from [CUnsignedChar] or Array<Uint8> to UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?

Tags: swift, pointers

How to convert from [CUnsignedChar] or Array to UnsafeMutablePointer?

I have the data array in the form of CUnsignedChar but need to call a function that expects UnsafeMutablePointer.

Details:

I am trying to call a C function in a third party framework from Swift that has this signature:

> int processData(unsigned char *data, int width, int height, int alpha,
>   int beta, void *handler, int *count, void **results);

My Swift code:

```
var width: Int32 = 0
var height: Int32 = 0
var length: Int32 = 1000

let count = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.allocate(capacity: 1) 
let results: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?> = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: 1)

var data = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(length))
processData(&data, width, height, 25, 1000, self.handler, count, results)
```

I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it hit processData call but not sure which thing in the call is triggering this. None of the variables seem to have the memory address Swift is complaining about.

Comment: You can just say `func foo(_ ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) {}; var a = [CUnsignedChar](); foo(&a)`. Note that `foo` must not persist the pointer for longer than the duration of the call. (I'm sure there's a dupe for this)

Comment: Unrelated, but I notice that you've been tagging your recent questions with the [swift4] tag. Note that this tag is only for questions *directly* related to changes in the language for that version. [swift] is for general language questions (such as this one). More people follow [swift], so you're getting your question out to a wider audience anyway! (and even when tagging [swift4], I would always include [swift] as well)

Comment: @Hamish When I follow your suggestion I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @Boon update your question

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of your function (please update your question with this), it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong; most likely cause is persisting the pointer for longer than the duration of the call or just reading out of its bounds. Both are undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Hamish Updated with more details.

Comment: @Boon Please post the implementation of `processData`.

Comment: @Hamish I don't have the implementation of processData. That's from a third party framework. Signature is all I have.

Comment: @Boon Okay, well you need to have a look at the documentation for the function then; what preconditions do you need to satisfy? Does `data` need to be manually allocated memory that the API will then deallocate at a later date?

Comment: @Hamish Yes data will be preallocated, hence the need to initialize it with the repeating char. Is everything else looking ok to you?

Comment: @Boon Okay, but the pointer you get by passing the array as an `&` argument is ephemeral, and is only valid for the duration of the call (after the function call ends, the compiler is free to release the array buffer). If it needs to last longer, you will need to allocate memory with `UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity:)` or possibly even `malloc` depending on how/if the API you're working with frees that memory.

Comment: @Hamish Understood - but it shouldn't cause memory crash at the call site right?

Comment: @Boon Correct, not unless the function is reading out of bounds; are you sure the buffer is big enough? Btw, what API is this? We cannot reproduce this without knowing.

Comment: @Hamish Bound by NDA so I can't disclose the API. Yes buffer is definitely big enough.