# How to convert from [Float] to UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> in Swift?

Tags: swift, pointers

I have an array of Float (i.e. [Float]) and I need to call a C function from Swift that expects `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`. What's the correct way to do the conversion?

Comment: The exact same way [I suggested in the comments of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573253/how-to-convert-from-cunsignedchar-or-arrayuint8-to-unsafemutablepointeruint#comment80100276_46573253) ;)

Comment: @Hamish Can you list that as an answer below and I will select it?

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4/5:**

if you want to ***copy*** your "Float" array ***into*** a ***new allocated memory*** use the following code:

```
// A float array
let floats : [Float] = [/* ... */] 

// Allocating sufficient space to store or data
let pointerToFloats = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: floats.count)

// Copying our data into the freshly allocated memory 
pointerToFloats.assign(from: floats, count: floats.count)

// Here you can use your pointer and pass it to any function
pointerWork(pointerToFloats)
```

But if you want to ***use*** ***the same memory*** of your current array use instead the following line:

```
let pointerToFloats = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.init(mutating: floats)
```

> Here you don't have to assign your data to the memory because the
>   pointer reference the same continuous memory of your float array

Comment: I went with the last line and for some bizarre reason I had to remove the ".init" in Swift 4.2 and just use: 
  let pointerToFloats = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(mutating: floats)

Comment: I agree it's bizarre but it does the same so ... :)

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to make same conversion, I used this code:

```
func someFunc(_ values: [Float]) {
    for value in values {
        //we need to make that value mutable. You can use inout to make parameters mutable, or use vars in "for in" statement
        var unsafeValue = value
        //then put that value to the C function using "&"
        someCFunc(value: &unsafeValue)
    }

}
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way, but it works for me

Comment: Did you mean to pass `unsafeValue` to the `someCFunc` function instead of `value`? And how is this passing the array to a C function? This is passing a single `Float`.

Comment: @rmaddy in the question, his C function requires single value, not an array. And I don't remember that C can receive arrays as parameters from swift. It can be only tuples

Comment: The function expects a pointer to a float, not a float. In C, a pointer to a float as function arg is equivalent to an array since you are pointing to the beginning of the array.

Comment: @Boon are you sure that your C function requires an array of floats as unsafepointer? I know that add &I make value as unsafe pointer, but it works only for a single value. When C func requires an array, then the swift code converts it to tuple. Could you show the original C function in your question?

Comment: @Woof The C function is from an SDK, I don't have access to it. Yes it's unsafe pointer - that's what the compiler indicates it is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer.contents().assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
```

here buffer is your allocated memory. `contents()` return a pointer of this memory and `assumingMemoryBound` cast the type you want for that memory block.